# Testing Hardware of MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown, apple-hardware-test

I have a strange problem [Sierra sudden shutdown and WiFi crashlogs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274813/sierra-sudden-shutdown-and-wifi-crashlogs).
So far I tested the hardware with Apple Hardware Test and some tools for RAM and GPU. None found a problem. Are there some others to try?

Comment: I've had a look at the other question and since your problem doesn't occur in Safe Mode it's almost 100% certain **not** to be a hardware issue (at least not in terms of the MacBook itself). What other hardware do you have connected to it? And are you sure all the software is compatible with your hardware and macOS Sierra?

Comment: Nothing at all. Only the original power cable.

Comment: This is the software installed on it https://github.com/geoHeil/dev-env/blob/master/osx-setup.sh I set up a second laptop now and will try to install only the basic system and see if this is still causing issues.

Comment: Excellent. What about software? Have you tried reinstalling the OS and **not** installing any 3rd party software and using the computer for a day or two with only its included software to see if the problem persists?

Comment: This is what I plan to do next.

Comment: Excellent! :) One thing, if the problem persists with nothing but a clean install, don't jump the gun and do anything. Let me know and I'd be happy to help you try to troubleshoot it. It'll be much easier to do with no other software installed. Of course, if the problem doesn't persist then we'll have narrowed down the possible cause. Either way troubleshooting is a process of elimination and requires a fair bit of patience, but hopefully now that you've got another laptop set up we can troubleshoot this one properly.

Comment: +1 I was already thinking about installing Linux on the macbook. ;)

Comment: @grgarside sorry, missed that fact that it was an internal link.

Comment: @Grarside, unfortunately, the Mac keeps crashing. Again. Here is the latest debug log of airport. https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/9d9ba8d7b6292cb1fd771a220e181459 Looking forward for any trouble shooting tips.